# Testing with mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

This is the first time I've tried to use mocha and chai, and I created this small test file `test.spec.js` where I put some tests.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var foo = 'bar';

describe('Test', function () {
it('Should exist', function () {
    expect(foo).to.exist;
});
it('Should be a string', function () {
    expect(foo).to.be.a('string');
});
it('Should equal bar', function () {
    expect(foo).to.equal('bar');
});
it('Should be at least 3 chars', function () {
    expect(foo).to.have.length.above(2);
});
});
```

This is in a separate file from where I have my "main" code.
But how do I go about testing the actual relevant code that I write in my script files?

I am not using ES6, so I can't import or require. But I am using npm, which is how I required chai.

So, my project looks like this

```
A folder
 - myscript.js
 - test.spec.js
```

How do I test myscript?

Comment: can you add myscript.js file

Comment: Do you use any script loader??

Answer (score -1):

Assign your tested script like this:

```
var myscript = require('./myscript.js');
```

Here's an example:

```
'use strict'

const expect = require('chai').expect
const myscript = require('./myscript.js')

describe('myscript', function () {
  it('should be a function', function() {
    expect(typeof myscript).to.equal('function')
  })

  it("should return an object with toString method", function() {
    expect(myscript().hasOwnProperty("toString")).to.be.true
  })
}) // etc...
```

Comment: Question talks about *how do I go about testing the actual relevant code that I write in my script files*

Comment: Oh... sorry about that. Why not simply assign var myscript = require('./myscript.js'); ?